# stat_compare_means compare groups not located on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm stuck on how to plot the mean p-values for grouped boxplots.

This is a portion of my data:

```
ID<-c('E5b','R6',"S22","E5b","R6","S22","E5b","R6","S22","E5b","R6","S22","E5b","R6","S22","E5b","R6",
      "S22","E5b","R6","S22","E5b","R6","S22","E5b","R6","S22","E5b","R6","S22")
value<-c(1.02048033657553e-05, 7.03779542465882e-07, 3.51889771232941e-07, 5.69459095210849e-06, 5.42341995438904e-07,
         1.08468399087781e-06, 1.15124329576991e-05, 2.34947611381614e-07, 4.69895222763228e-07, 1.02807349661977e-05,
         2.12704861369607e-06, 0, 1.90550741185218e-06, 1.52440592948174e-06, 0, 1.23540828390671e-06, 4.11802761302236e-07,
         0, 5.22781921260155e-06, 1.04556384252031e-06, 0, 1.71521997010029e-06, 0, 2.05826396412034e-06, 4.18012063828162e-06,
         0, 7.60021934233022e-07, 2.93951950197596e-05, 0, 2.31458228502044e-07)
condition<-c("E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R",
             "R","R","S","S","S","S","S","S","S","S","S")
family<-c("Unassigned","Unassigned","Siphoviridae","Unassigned","Unassigned","Siphoviridae","Unassigned","Unassigned",
          "Siphoviridae","Unassigned","Unassigned","Siphoviridae","Unassigned","Unassigned","Siphoviridae","Unassigned",
          "Unassigned","Siphoviridae","Unassigned","Unassigned","Siphoviridae","Unassigned","Unassigned","Siphoviridae",
          "Unassigned","Unassigned","Siphoviridae","Unassigned","Unassigned","Siphoviridae")
df <- data.frame(ID,value,condition,family)


my_comparisons <- list(c("E","R"),c("E","S"),c("R","S"))

p <- ggboxplot(df, x = "ID", y = "value",
          color = "condition", 
          palette = "jco",add = "jitter")+
        facet_wrap(~family,scales='free_x')
p + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, bracket.size = .4, size = 8)+
stat_compare_means(method = 't.test', size = 3)
```

This is only showing the p-value for one group?

```
Warning message:
"Computation failed in `stat_signif()`:
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
```

[image]

[Apparently](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/65) stat_compare_means can only compare the groups that are on the x-axis. Is there any way to plot bars and their p-values between all bars?

Ideally I want to create something as below except with ID on the x-axis. Any help greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add (aes(group = condition) inside stat_compare_means.

```
  p <- ggboxplot(df, x = "ID", y = "value",
                  color = "condition", 
                  palette = "jco",add = "jitter")+
                  facet_wrap(~family,scales='free_x')+
                  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+
                  stat_compare_means(aes(group = condition),size=3)
```

[image]